# jquery draggable droppable remove dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

How would one remove the item from the shopping cart?

Naturally you would want to be able to drag and drop the item back.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#catalog" ).accordion();
        $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                $( "" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
                // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
                // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                .addClass("cart-item")
                .appendTo(this);
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
    $("#catalog ul").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        },
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: '.cart-item'
    });
});
```

**Notes**:

- When an item is dropped on the cart area, I've added a class of `cart-item` to the new item.
- I've made the catalog's `ul` droppable; this area only accepts `cart-item`s.  It calls `remove()` to remove an item from the cart once the drop has occurred.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/t97FE/embedded/result/

You can drag an item back from the cart to any category in the catalog, but I think it would be pretty easy to make items only draggable to their original categories.

Comment: ... TY ... so much!  This is going to help a lot of people with the same issue!

Comment: Hi Andrew +1, what if we want to add a close button (close looking hyperlink) to the item in the cart instead of drag and drop back? I guess in that case I do not need `catalog li.droppable` function. How to go about that using your code?

Comment: @aspiring: Here's an example of what you could do: http://jsfiddle.net/t97FE/246/. Basically, add a close link to the `li` that's appended to the shopping cart. Add a "click" handler that removes the parent `li` when it's clicked