# JQuery, Draggable remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have implemented a shopping cart like drag-drop nodes.
http://jsfiddle.net/dkonline/Tw46Y/

Here once dropped item cannot be removed from bucket(slot). I want to implement that feature. Items can be removed from right-hand side list. I checked online and found this.
[jquery draggable droppable remove dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800299/jquery-draggable-droppable-remove-dropped)

```
$("#catalog ul").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    },
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: '.cart-item'
});
```

But the solution provided in the link not working for me. I am new in jquery. Please let me know what I am missing. Any other way of removing items is also welcoming.

Comment: Ok, I got downvote. I always get. :-( But can I get a feedback please.

Comment: Um actually, none of your other questions have downvotes. That being said, whoever downvoted this *should* provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have `$( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();` instead of `$(ui.draggable).remove();`. Just change that and it will work.
$(this) is the target for the drop. `ui` is the element being dragged/dropped.